# Windows Gadget resize fail

Tags: javascript, html, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have a windows gadget that dies when I close a flyout using the following code:

```
function CheckDockState() {
    System.Gadget.beginTransition();

    var oBody = document.body.style;
    if (System.Gadget.docked) {
        oBody.height = 80;
    } else {
        oBody.height = 800; 
    }
    System.Gadget.endTransition(System.Gadget.TransitionType.morph, timeTransition);
}
function flyoutClose() {
    CheckDockState();
    System.Gadget.Flyout.show = false;
}
```

Now, this works **fine** but when I close the flyout - I cannot resize the gadget (using the little "larger version" button)...

Has anyone else had this problem?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I beat you all to it..

Turns out that the System.Gadget declarations need to be in the loaded() function.

e.g.

```
function loaded() {  
    System.Gadget.onDock = CheckDockState;
    System.Gadget.onUndock = CheckDockState;
    System.Gadget.settingsUI = "settings.html";
    System.Gadget.onSettingsClosed = SettingsClosed;
    System.Gadget.Flyout.file = "flyout.html";
    CheckDockState();
}
```

Before, I had them just at the top of the file.